# Android getPixels() possibly a silly mistake?

Tags: android, bitmap

Okay, this is quite simple to understand, but for some bizarre reason I can't get it working.. I've simplified this example from the actual code.

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.someimage);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
try
{
    int[] pixels = new int[32*32];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 800, 0, 0, 32, 32);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
{
    Log.e("testing", "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", ex);
}
```

Why on earth do I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? the pixels array is 32x32 and as far as I'm aware I'm correctly using getPixels. The image dimensions is 800x800 and I am attempting to retrieve a 32x32 section. The image is a 32-bit PNG which is being reported as ARGB-8888.

Any ideas? even if I'm being an idiot! I'm about to throw the keyboard out of the window :D

Comment: I feel really bad that the first guy who answered this actually lead me to fixing it, the answer, as all have said, is because of the stride. The documentation on the stride value is misleading as it does not indicate whether it is the source file or destination file. I assumed it needed to know how many pixels to skip before the next 'row sample' of data;

Comment: Thanks all for your help and yes I was being an idiot! Nikolay: yeah sadly I was thinking in the reverse :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overflowing the destination buffer because you're asking for a stride of 800 entries between rows.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)

Answer (score 10):

use bitmap width as stride, in ur case 32

```
 bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 32, 0, 0, 32, 32);
```

every row gap with 800 causes ur pixelarray to get out of bound

"I'm about to throw the keyboard out of the window " funny lol

Comment: thanks for this but Julian did answer first I'm afraid ;) vote up to compensate.

Comment: its ok. np, i was writin my answer that time :(

Answer (score 3):

You getting OutOfBounds exception becacuse stride is applied to  pixels array not to the original bitmap,so in your case you're trying to retrieve 32*800 pixels which doesn't fit into your array.