# Get single column of pixels from bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to analyse the RGB values of pixels in a bitmap. I can scan the bitmap one row at a time using the following code...

```
private void analyseImage() {
    int w = imageBitmap.getWidth();
    int h = imageBitmap.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[w];

    for (int vPos = 0; vPos < h; vPos++) {
        imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, vPos, w, 1);
        for (int hPos = 0; hPos < w; hPos++) {
            if ((pixels[hPos] & 0x00FFFFFF) != 0x00FFFFFF) {
                Log.d(TAG, "analyseImage - found object pixel: " + pixels[hPos] + ", " + hPos + ", " + vPos);
        }
    }
}
```

That works absolutely fine and identifies the pixels which have any other colour than pure white (my background colour).

Ideally what I want to do is to get a column of pixels each time instead of a row but I think I'm misunderstanding the `stride` parameter of `getPixels(...)` and the following `for` loop throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
int[] pixels = new int[h];

for (int hPos = 0; hPos < w; hPos++) {
    imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, hPos, 0, 1, h);
    for (int vPos = 0; vPos < h; vPos++) {
        if ((pixels[vPos] & 0x00FFFFFF) != 0x00FFFFFF) {
            Log.d(TAG, "analyseImage - found object pixel: " + pixels[hPos] + ", " + hPos + ", " + vPos);
        }
    }
}
```

As I said I'm obviously misunderstanding how `stride` works but I assumed I could read one column at a time using the above. Is there an easy way to read a column at a time or do I have to do it manually with repeated calls to `getPixel(int x, int y)` to build my own column array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed misinterpreting stride, stride is a skip parameter for the RETURNED integer array.  What you want is for stride to be 1, as you want there to be essentially NO skip in the returned array of values.  You are going past the end of your new allocated array because you are using a stride of the width of the original image.  Move from and to below, and tell me the result.

From:

```
imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, hPos, 0, 1, h);
```

To:

```
imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 1, hPos, 0, 1, h);
```

From the exceptions portion of this function definition:

**Throws:**
**IllegalArgumentException**     if x, y, width, height exceed the bounds of the bitmap, or if abs(stride) < width.

In your case, width is actually only 1.

Comment: Thanks - I'd literally just solved it when I finally found this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364188/android-getpixels-possibly-a-silly-mistake and was going to provide my own answer but you got there first. As mentioned in that question the docs are misleading and the stride should indeed be the width of the sub-bitmap of the `pixels`  array and not that of the original bitmap. Similar to the OP of that question I was about to throw my keyboard out of the window. :)

Comment: @Squonk - LOL, actually, the docs are written correctly, it is just the fact that our minds tend to think it has to do with the original image, I had to read it like 3 times myself to understand :-)  Don't throw your keyboard out, you are a great almost 25K point SO leader, you have tons to contribute!

Comment: Well I knew I had to be reading it incorrectly but couldn't understand why. It definitely says it's related to the `pixels` array but then says it must be >= to bitmap's width so, yeah, that's why the natural assumption is that it's referring to the original bitmap. I still think it could do with clarification though. As for throwing my keyboard out the window - nah, that'll never really happen. Thanks for the compliment - I try to visit SO a few times a day and try to help out where I can - solving other people's problems is a great way of learning too.